# Data-type misalignment with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, memory, logging

After adding the following Delphi function, I'm receiving an error regarding data-type misalignment: `Project ... faulted with message: 'datatype misalignment at 0x77a7d7d8'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.`

The function I've added is below. Note that the function actually completes successfully, although only the timestamp is actually written to the file.

```
procedure Log(msg : String);
var
  tempFolderChars : array [0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  tempFolder : string;
  logFile : TextFile;
  dt : TDateTime;
begin
  GetTempPath(SizeOf(tempFolderChars), tempFolderChars);
  tempFolder := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(String(tempFolderChars));
  dt := Now();

  AssignFile(logFile, tempFolder + 'GenericHolding.txt');
  if FileExists(tempFolder + 'GenericHolding.txt') then
    Append(logFile)
  else
    ReWrite(logFile);

  Write(logFile, FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss ', now));
  Write(logFile, msg);
  Write(logFile, #13, #10);
  CloseFile(logFile);
end;
```

**EDIT**: Added more assembly output.

```
ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess:
77BAFAC8 B816000000       mov eax,$00000016
77BAFACD 33C9             xor ecx,ecx
77BAFACF 8D542404         lea edx,[esp+$04]
77BAFAD3 64FF15C0000000   call dword ptr fs:[$000000c0]
77BAFADA 83C404           add esp,$04
77BAFADD C21400           ret $0014
```

Comment: Could you please post what is at address `0x77a7d7d8`? And maybe a stack trace?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using your code (copy/pasted directly into a D2007 project). What Delphi version and OS are you using?

Comment: IIRC, the version of Delphi is really important as a simple type cast would not always work. In the older versions of Delphi you would need to use StrPas. Another thing that would help is the contents of msg that you are passing in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Char` is `AnsiChar` (`SizeOf(Char)=1`) in Delphi 2007 and earlier, but is `WideChar` (`SizeOf(Char)=2`) in Delphi 2009 and later.

`GetTempPath()` expects the first parameter to specify the **number of characters** that your buffer can hold, but you are specifying the **number of bytes** instead.

In Delphi 2007 and earlier, `SizeOf(tempFolderChars)` and `Length(tempFolderChars)` will be the same value, but in Delphi 2009 and later they will not be the same.  In that latter case, you are telling `GetTempPath()` that you can accept twice as many characters as you really can.

You need to change `SizeOf(tempFolderChars)` to `Length(tempFolderChars)`.  You also need to pay attention to the return value of `GetTempPath()`, as it tells you how many **characters** were actually written into the buffer.

Try this instead:

```
procedure Log(msg : String);
var
  tempFolderChars : array [0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  tempFolder : string;
  len: DWORD;
  ...
begin
  len := GetTempPath(Length(tempFolderChars), tempFolderChars);
  if len = 0 then Exit;
  SetString(tempFolder, tempFolderChars, len);
  tempFolder := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(tempFolder);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I actually already know about the `SomeFuncA` vs `SomeFuncW` situation from my C++ Win32 API days, but I only just learnt that this applies to (what I though was) the *integral* type `Char` (`AnsiChar` vs `WideChar`). Thanks.